# JS group by month/year of date

Tags: javascript

I have an array with date and id's I want to convert it group by month and by year year

oldest date/month should be at first

```
let myArray = [
  {project_id: 444, date: "2021-08-17 14:33:49"},
  {project_id: 444, date: "2021-08-16 14:33:50"},
  {project_id: 555, date: "2020-08-16 14:33:50"},
  {project_id: 666, date: "2020-08-17 12:33:50"},
  {project_id: 666, date: "2020-09-17 12:33:50"},
  {project_id: 666, date: "2020-09-17 12:33:50"},
];
```

The below array is my actual requirement that is manually converted from the above array
eg:

```
[
  {
    "month_year": "Aug 2020",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2020-08-16 14:33:50",
        "project_id": 666
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-08-17 12:33:50",
        "project_id": 777
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "month_year": "Sep 2020",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "22020-09-17 12:33:50",
        "project_id": 666
      },
      {
        "date": "2020-09-17 12:33:50",
        "project_id": 666
      }
    ]
  },
   {
    "month_year": "Aug 2021",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2021-08-17 14:33:49",
        "project_id": 444
      },
      {
        "date": "2021-08-16 14:33:50",
        "project_id": 444
      }
    ]
  },
  
]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Hello! Take a look at Javascript dates; https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp perhaps if your initial array contains dates by Unix epoch (var date = New Date()) they'll be easier to manipulate as you can then loop through them with .getYear(), .getMonth() before pushing them to their output array!

Comment: Did you attempt anything?

Comment: Also if you're wanting to use your 'id' as well, an id make sure they're unique; depending on the scale of your project, again, the current epoch time is a great ID source. Regardless, without answering your question look at for-in loops!

Comment: To add to the helpful comments already on this question, note that JavaScript's `new Date()` constructor also accepts a string parameter, so you can call, for example, `new Date("2021-08-17 14:33:49")` to convert your object's date strings into valid dates to parse and sort by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function groupByDate(list) {
  const monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
  ];
  let result = [];

  for (let obj of list) {
    let objDate = new Date(obj.date);
    let monthYear = `${monthNames[objDate.getMonth()]} ${objDate.getFullYear()}`;

    let foundMatch = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      if (result[i].month_year === monthYear) {
        result[i].data.push(obj);
        foundMatch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!foundMatch) {
      result.push({
        "month_year": monthYear,
         "data": [obj]
      });
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Basically it loops over each object in the list, and if the current date (month and year only) hasn't already been processed, it will add another json object to the result list. If the current date have been processed before, it adds it to the correct json.

Working JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dfhg41sx/1/